# Beautifulsoap loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Estoy tratando de seleccionar una serie de elementos dentro de una pagina web. En realidad 6. Utilizando este código consigo los elementos que quiero pero también muchos elementos que no quiero, después del sexto.

Como podria programar un loop que solo seleccione los 6 primeros elementos que se llaman class_ = "negritas" y sus siblings?

```
for negritas in soup.find_all(class_ = "negritas"):
  print (negritas.get_text())
  print (negritas.nextSibling.get_text())
```

trate este código pero no entiendo como decirle que solo los 6 primeros:

```
divs = soup.findAll(class_= 'negritas')    
for div in divs:

    div.find()
```

Comment: Entiendo que `soup.findAll()` devuelve una lista, si es así podrías hacer `divs = soup.findAll(class_= 'negritas') [:6]` para "recortar" los primeros 6 elementos

Comment: Wow, funciono increible, muchismas gracias.